# How to make unique identifier by specific digit and data entry

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm trying to make unique number for ticket which can be identified based on digit and data entry.

For example :

- **10110239** (The 11th event of music festival, order number 239)
- 20100020 (The 10th event of dance festival, order number 20)
- 30051304 (The 5th event of photo festival, order number 1304)

*first equation :*

**1** (1st digit) is for the category of the ticket (e.g : 1 for music festival, 2 for dance festival, 3 for photo festival)

*second equation :*

**011** (2nd, 3rd, 4th digit) is for the cumulative of the category, for example this category of event is the 11th time

*third equation :*

**0239** (5th,6th,7th,8th) is for the participant's order, then this is the 239th participant

Is there anyone who can help with the logic in laravel controller?

---

I have 2 tables 
(T_EVENT and T_EVENT_PARTICIPANT)

Basically, Admin input an Event detail and saved into T_EVENT(name, category, date) then user can register and saved into T_EVENT_PARTICIPANT(name,tiket_number,timestamps)

My logic is for the 1st equation I can use category from T_EVENT, 
for 2nd equation I will count category from T_EVENT with the same categoy, then for 3rd equation I will use iteration.

Maybe there's someone who can make it simple?

Comment: I got headache after I read it :>

Comment: have you tried anything with script logic so far? or you are asking us to create instead?

Comment: @RamChander I just got one after posted this question, I just want to know how other will think with their logic

Comment: What is the input? I don't understand the question. It look more like a request or a description.

Comment: @Andreas Ok, I'll edit the post

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str_pad();` in your controller, something like:

```
function createUniqeIdentifier(int $ticketCatId, int $catId, int $participantId) {
  return $ticketCatId.str_pad($catId, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad($participantId, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

print_r(createUniqeIdentifier(1,12,22)); // Prints 10120022
```

BR